# Hosting playn application on Google sites

Tags: playn, google-gadget, google-sites

I am trying to host a client-only (no network, no persistence) PlayN game on Google Sites. Anyone know an easy way to do this?

My first attempt was to upload the game.nocache.js file to a "file cabinet" and load it from a script tag in a page html, but Sites cuts out script tags.

My next attempt was to create a simple gadget that loaded the script from the file cabinet, since I've used gadgets to get around the script-embedding issue before. The gadget looks like this:

```
<Module>
    <ModulePrefs title="PlayN Gadget"  width="800" height="600" />
    <Content type="html">
        <![CDATA[
             <div id='playn-root'></div>
             <script src="files/game.nocache.js"></script> 
        ]]>
     </Content>
</Module>
```

(Where 'files' is the name of the file cabinet page.) However, this gives an html validation error upon trying to include the module, an unclosed META tag somewhere deep in the js file.

Anyone have success with this?